# How to identify gaps in reported year in an unbalanced panel with repeated observations for firm-year?

Tags: loops, stata, dummy-variable

I have a dataset at the firm-product-year level. I want to identify which firms having gaps in reporting years between 1994-2004. Consider an example below:

```
clear       
input       id  year    sales   product
14  1994    28.9    2
14  1994    67.9    3
14  1994    12.5    9
14  1994    451.8   34
14  1994    27.5    44
14  1994    647.6   45
14  1995    9.7 2
14  1995    33.5    3
14  1995    112.4   9
14  1995    712.2   15
14  1995    902.3   41
14  1995    67.3    45
14  1995    15.1    50
14  1996    6.5 2
14  1996    24.6    3
14  1996    1009.4  5
14  1996    77.1    9
14  1996    76.9    17
14  1996    12.4    45
14  1996    946.3   88
14  1996    15.4    92
14  1997    .7  2
14  1997    63.2    2
14  1997    91.7    3
14  1997    860.8   9
14  1997    12.4    21
14  1997    800.8   32
14  1997    33.7    45
14  1997    41  95
15  1999    .1  44
15  2000    .1  58
15  2001    .4  27
15  2001    .1  95
15  2002    .5  5
15  2002    .1  58
15  2003    .1  17
15  2004    3.5 28
15  2004    .1  39
16  2000    .8  2
16  2001    .6  2
16  2003    .2  2
16  2004    .1  2
16  2004    .1  8
16  2004    2.5 8
end
```

Firm 14 produced 6 products in 1994. It produced every year consecutively until 1997. Because there are no missing years in between, I keep this firm. But firm 16 reports in 2000, 2001 and then in 2003. I assume that the firm still operated in 2002 but doesn't report in the data. How to create a dummy variable for this firm?

`tsfill` doesn't help because I have repeated values within id-year.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: You can create id2 that combines id and product (egen, group), re-xtset, and then tsfill the gaps.

Answer (score -1):

In the first step, you delete the companies that do not produce any products in a year by creating a dummy variable "firm_any_production" that indicates whether a company has produced at least one product in a given year. Then the maximum of this dummy variable is calculated for each firm and the firms for which the maximum is 0 are deleted.

```
gen firm_any_production = sum(sales) > 0
bysort id (year): egen firm_missing_year = max(firm_any_production)
drop if firm_missing_year == 0
```

In step 2 you calculate whether the newly added products of a company have higher sales than the core product. This is calculated by creating a dummy variable "is_new_product", which indicates whether a product is a new product. Then the sales of these new products are calculated and compared to the sales of the core product. If the sum of the turnover of the new products is greater than the turnover of the core product, another dummy variable "greater_than_core" is created and set to 1.

```
bysort id year: egen core_product_sales = max(sales)
gen is_new_product = sales != core_product_sales
gen new_product_sales = sales * is_new_product
gen greater_than_core = sum(new_product_sales) > core_product_sales
```

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Added:

The code is creating a firm_missing_year variable that takes the value of 1 if a firm doesn't report any product in the current year. The is_core_product variable indicates which product has the highest sales in a given year for each firm. The is_new_product variable takes the value of 1 if the product wasn't produced in the previous year. Finally, the higher_new_sales variable takes the value of 1 if the sum of sales of new products is greater than the sales of the core product.

```
use "your_data_file.dta", clear

gen firm_missing_year = 0

bysort id (year): egen last_year = max(year), unique(id)

replace firm_missing_year = 1 if year > last_year[1]

gen is_core_product = 0

bysort id year: egen max_sales = max(sales), unique(id year)

replace is_core_product = 1 if sales == max_sales

gen is_new_product = 0

bysort id year: gen lagged_product = product[_n-1]

replace is_new_product = 1 if product != lagged_product & sales != max_sales

bysort id year: egen sum_new_sales = sum(sales * is_new_product), unique(id year)

gen higher_new_sales = 0

replace higher_new_sales = 1 if sum_new_sales > max_sales
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the first part of the code doesn't work for me. firm_missing_year is 1 for all observations. Second, is_new_product is not correctly defined because firm 14 produced already in 1994 products 2, 3, 9, 45. So they are not new products in 1995. I think first we need to create a dummy indicating which products were not produced in t-1 but are produced in t. Can you please help me?

Comment: @user173192 check out the answer I added the solution with some comment

Comment: @webapp471 - what question are you answering? Please note that the OP has shown no work, only posting a set of requirements (maybe an assignment?) - please don't answer such off-topic questions.